# Velero + MinIO: Unknown desc = AuthorizationHeaderMalformed: The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong;

Tags: kubernetes, minio, velero

I'm getting this issue below. Anyone has an idea what could be wrong?

```
user@master-1:~$ kubectl logs -n velero velero-77b544f457-dw4hf
# REMOVED
An error occurred: some backup storage locations are invalid: backup store for location "aws" is invalid: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = AuthorizationHeaderMalformed: The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-west-2'
    status code: 400, request id: A3Q97JKM6GQRNABA, host id: b6g0on189w6hYgCrId/Xr0BP44pXjZPy2SqK2t7bn/+Ggq9FUY2N3KQHYRcMEuCCHY2L2vfsYEo=; backup store for location "velero" is invalid: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = AuthorizationHeaderMalformed: The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-west-2'
    status code: 400, request id: YF6DRKN7MYSXVBV4, host id: Y8/Gufd7R0BlZCIZqbJPfdAjVqK8+WLfWoANBDnipDkH421/vGt0Ne2E/yZw2bYf7rfms+rGxsg=
user@master-1:~$
```

I have installed Velero 1.4.2 with Helm chart:

```
user@master-1:~$ helm search repo velero --versions | grep -e 2.12.17 -e NAME
NAME                CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION
vmware-tanzu/velero 2.12.17         1.4.2       A Helm chart for velero
user@master-1:~$
```

I used this command to install:

```
helm install velero vmware-tanzu/velero --namespace velero --version 2.12.17 -f velero-values.yaml \
--set-file credentials.secretContents.cloud=/home/era/creds-root.txt \
--set configuration.provider=aws \
--set configuration.backupStorageLocation.name=velero \
--set configuration.backupStorageLocation.bucket="velero" \
--set configuration.backupStorageLocation.prefix="" \
--set configuration.backupStorageLocation.config.region="us-east-1" \
--set image.repository=velero/velero \
--set image.tag=v1.4.2 \
--set image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent \
--set initContainers[0].name=velero-plugin-for-aws \
--set initContainers[0].image=velero/velero-plugin-for-aws:v1.1.0 \
--set initContainers[0].volumeMounts[0].mountPath=/target \
--set initContainers[0].volumeMounts[0].name=plugins \
--replace
```

My credential files passed:

```
$ cat creds-root.txt
[default]
aws_access_key_id=12345678
aws_secret_access_key=12345678
```

Helm values file:

```
user@master-1:~$ cat velero-values.yaml
configuration:
  provider: aws
  backupStorageLocation:
    name: minio
    provider: aws
    # caCert: null
    bucket: velero
    config:
      region: us-east-1
credentials:
  useSecret: true
  existingSecret: cloud-credentials
  secretContents: {}
  extraEnvVars: {}
backupsEnabled: true
snapshotsEnabled: true
deployRestic: true
```

MinIO snapshot resource (MinIO is working at 192.168.2.239:9000):

```
# For MinIO
---
apiVersion: velero.io/v1
kind: VolumeSnapshotLocation
metadata:
  name: minio
  namespace: velero
spec:
  provider: openebs.io/cstor-blockstore
  config:
    bucket: velero

    prefix: cstor

    provider: aws

    # The region where the server is located.
    region: us-east-1

    # profile for credential, if not mentioned then plugin will use profile=default
    profile: user1

    # Whether to use path-style addressing instead of virtual hosted bucket addressing.
    # Set to "true"
    s3ForcePathStyle: "true"

    # S3 URL, By default it will be generated from "region" and "bucket"
    s3Url: http://192.168.2.239:9000

    # You can specify the multipart_chunksize  here for explicitness.
    # multiPartChunkSize can be from 5Mi(5*1024*1024 Bytes) to 5Gi
    # For more information: https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-server-limits-per-tenant.html
    # If not set then it will be calculated from the file size
    multiPartChunkSize: 64Mi

    # If MinIO is configured with custom certificate then certificate can be passed to plugin through caCert
    # Value of caCert must be base64 encoded
    # To encode, execute command: cat ca.crt |base64 -w 0
    # caCert: LS0tLS1CRU...tRU5EIENFUlRJRklDQVRFLS0tLS0K

    # If you want to disable certificate verification then set insecureSkipTLSVerify to "true"
    # By default insecureSkipTLSVerify is set to "false"
    insecureSkipTLSVerify: "true"
```

aws resource which seems failing:

```
$ k get backupstoragelocation -n velero aws -o yaml
apiVersion: velero.io/v1
kind: BackupStorageLocation
metadata:
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation
  creationTimestamp: "2021-04-15T08:23:38Z"
  generation: 3
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: velero
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: velero
    helm.sh/chart: velero-2.12.17
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: velero.io/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:helm.sh/hook: {}
          f:helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
          f:helm.sh/chart: {}
      f:spec:
        .: {}
        f:config:
          .: {}
          f:region: {}
        f:objectStorage:
          .: {}
          f:prefix: {}
        f:provider: {}
    manager: Go-http-client
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-04-15T08:23:38Z"
  - apiVersion: velero.io/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        f:objectStorage:
          f:bucket: {}
    manager: kubectl-edit
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-04-15T17:52:46Z"
  name: aws
  namespace: velero
  resourceVersion: "1333724"
  selfLink: /apis/velero.io/v1/namespaces/velero/backupstoragelocations/aws
  uid: a51033b2-e53d-4751-9110-c9649de6aa67
spec:
  config:
    region: us-east-1
  objectStorage:
    bucket: velero
    prefix: backup
  provider: aws
user@master-1:~$
```

For some reason no plugins are listed:

```
user@master-1:~$ velero plugin get
user@master-1:~$
```

Velero is obviously crashing because of original issue:

```
user@master-1:~$ kubectl get pods -n velero
NAME                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
restic-nqpsl              1/1     Running            0          7m52s
restic-pw897              1/1     Running            0          7m52s
restic-rtwzd              1/1     Running            0          7m52s
velero-77b544f457-dw4hf   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          5m59s
user@master-1:~$
```

More resources:

```
user@master-1:~$ k get BackupStorageLocation -n velero
NAME     PHASE   LAST VALIDATED   AGE
aws                               10h
velero                            11m
user@master-1:~$ k get volumesnapshotlocation -n velero
NAME              AGE
default           11m
minio             39h
velero-snapshot   9h
user@master-1:~$
```

My MinIO service is started using Docker Compose and working fine:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  minio:
    container_name: minio
    hostname: minio
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "0.0.0.0:9000:9000"
    environment:
      # ROOT
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: 12345678
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: 12345678
      MINIO_REGION: us-east-1
    command: server --address :9000 /data
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

Unknown PHASE for backup locations:

```
user@master-1:~$ velero get backup-locations
NAME     PROVIDER   BUCKET/PREFIX   PHASE     LAST VALIDATED   ACCESS MODE
aws      aws        velero/backup   Unknown   Unknown          ReadWrite
velero   aws        velero          Unknown   Unknown          ReadWrite
user@master-1:~$
```

Test MinIO access separately:

```
bash-4.3# AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=12345678 AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=12345678 aws s3api get-bucket-location --endpoint-url http://192.168.2.239:9000 --bucket velero
{
    "LocationConstraint": "us-east-1"
}
bash-4.3#
```

Secrets are correct:

```
user@master-1:~$ k get secret -n velero cloud-credentials -o yaml | head -n 4
apiVersion: v1
data:
  cloud: W2RlZmF-REMOVED
kind: Secret
user@master-1:~$

user@master-1:~$ k get secret -n velero
NAME                           TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
cloud-credentials              Opaque                                1      91m
default-token-8rwhg            kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      2d20h
sh.helm.release.v1.velero.v1   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      45m
velero                         Opaque                                0      2d19h
velero-restic-credentials      Opaque                                1      40h
velero-server-token-8zm9k      kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      45m
user@master-1:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was missing configuration:

```
--set configuration.backupStorageLocation.config.s3Url="http://192.168.2.239:9000" \
--set configuration.backupStorageLocation.config.s3ForcePathStyle=true \
```